# How to upload multiple files using lightning component?

Tags: lightning

Trying to upload multiple files using lightning component. I upload multiple files same file name create multiple time.(not working properly)

This is my code: could you please help on this?

### Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class FileUploadController {


    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id saveChunk(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType, String fileId) {
        // check if fileId id ''(Always blank in first chunk), then call the saveTheFile method,
        //  which is save the check data and return the attachemnt Id after insert, 
        //  next time (in else) we are call the appentTOFile() method
        //   for update the attachment with reamins chunks   
        if (fileId == '') {
            fileId = saveTheFile('0012v00002aIYgy', fileName, base64Data, contentType);
        } else {
            appendToFile(fileId, base64Data);
        }

        return Id.valueOf(fileId);
    }

    public static Id saveTheFile(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType) {
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');

        Attachment oAttachment = new Attachment();
        oAttachment.parentId = '0012v00002aIYgy';

        oAttachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
        oAttachment.Name = fileName;
        oAttachment.ContentType = contentType;

        insert oAttachment;

        return oAttachment.Id;
    }


}
```

---

### Lighhtning Component:

```
<aura:component controller="FileUploadController">
 <!-- 'parentId' Aura Attribute for store the Id for Parent Record where we are attach our file -->  
   <aura:attribute name="parentId" type="Id" default="0016F000024nYzwQAE" />
 <!-- 'showLoadingSpinner' attribute for show/hide the uploading image and msg in aura:if-->
   <aura:attribute name="showLoadingSpinner" type="boolean" default="false" />
 <!-- 'fileName' attribute for display the selected file name -->  
   <aura:attribute name="fileName" type="String" default="No File Selected.." />
 <!-- Lightning Input with file type and on file change call the 'handleFilesChange' controller --> 

   <lightning:input aura:id="fileId" onchange="{!c.handleFilesChange}" type="file" name="file" label="Upload Attachment" multiple="true"/>
   <div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error">{!v.fileName} </div>

 <!--use aura:if for show-hide the loading spinner image--> 
   <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showLoadingSpinner}">
      <div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error">Uploading... 
         <img src="/auraFW/resources/aura/images/spinner.gif" class="spinner-img" alt="Loading"/>'
      </div>
   </aura:if>

 <br/>

   <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.doSave}">Upload Attachment</button>
</aura:component>
```

---

### Controller.js:

```
({
    doSave: function(component, event, helper) {
        if (component.find("fileId").get("v.files").length > 0) {
            helper.uploadHelper(component, event);
        } else {
            alert('Please Select a Valid File');
        }
    },

    handleFilesChange: function(component, event, helper) {
        var fileName = 'No File Selected..';
        if (event.getSource().get("v.files").length > 0) {
            fileName = event.getSource().get("v.files")[0]['name'];
        }
        component.set("v.fileName", fileName);
    },
})
```

---

Helper.js:

---

```
 ({
    MAX_FILE_SIZE: 4500000, //Max file size 4.5 MB 
    CHUNK_SIZE: 750000,      //Chunk Max size 750Kb 

    uploadHelper: function(component, event) {
        // start/show the loading spinner   
        component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", true);
        // get the selected files using aura:id [return array of files]
        var fileInput = component.find("fileId").get("v.files");
        // get the first file using array index[0]  

        for(var i = 0; i < fileInput.length; i++){

            //alert(JSON.stringify(fileInput[i]));

            var file = fileInput[i];
        var self = this;
        // check the selected file size, if select file size greter then MAX_FILE_SIZE,
        // then show a alert msg to user,hide the loading spinner and return from function  
        if (file.size > self.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
            component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", false);
            component.set("v.fileName", 'Alert : File size cannot exceed ' + self.MAX_FILE_SIZE + ' bytes.\n' + ' Selected file size: ' + file.size);
            return;
        }

        // create a FileReader object 
        var objFileReader = new FileReader();
        // set onload function of FileReader object   
        objFileReader.onload = $A.getCallback(function() {
            var fileContents = objFileReader.result;
            var base64 = 'base64,';
            var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;

            fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
            // call the uploadProcess method 
            self.uploadProcess(component, file, fileContents);
        });

        objFileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }

    },



       uploadProcess: function(component, file, fileContents) {
            // set a default size or startpostiton as 0 
            var startPosition = 0;
            // calculate the end size or endPostion using Math.min() function which is return the min. value   
            var endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);

            // start with the initial chunk, and set the attachId(last parameter)is null in begin
            this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, '');
        },


        uploadInChunk: function(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, attachId) {
            // call the apex method 'saveChunk'
            var getchunk = fileContents.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
            var action = component.get("c.saveChunk");
            action.setParams({
                parentId: component.get("v.parentId"),
                fileName: file.name,
                //fileName:'RaghuUpload',
                base64Data: encodeURIComponent(getchunk),
                contentType: file.type,
                //contentType: '.pptx',
                fileId: attachId
            });

            // set call back 
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                // store the response / Attachment Id   
                attachId = response.getReturnValue();
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    // update the start position with end postion
                    startPosition = endPosition;
                    endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);
                    // check if the start postion is still less then end postion 
                    // then call again 'uploadInChunk' method , 
                    // else, diaply alert msg and hide the loading spinner
                    if (startPosition < endPosition) {
                        this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, attachId);
                    } else {
                        alert('your File is uploaded successfully');
                        component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", false);
                    }
                    // handel the response errors        
                } else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
                } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors) {
                        if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                            console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown error");
                    }
                }
            });
            // enqueue the action
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    })
```

---

### Lightning application :

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:fileUpload/>
<!-- here c: is org. default namespace prefix-->
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is at FileReader object creation. Try to change helper and apex controller like below. It will wotk.

Helper.js

```
  ({
    MAX_FILE_SIZE: 4500000, //Max file size 4.5 MB 
    CHUNK_SIZE: 750000,      //Chunk Max size 750Kb 

    uploadHelper: function(component, event) {
        // start/show the loading spinner   
        component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", true);
        // get the selected files using aura:id [return array of files]
        var fileInput = component.find("fileId").get("v.files");
        // get the first file using array index[0]  
        for(var i = 0; i < fileInput.length; i++){
            var file = fileInput[i];
            var self = this;
            // check the selected file size, if select file size greter then MAX_FILE_SIZE,
            // then show a alert msg to user,hide the loading spinner and return from function  
            if (file.size > self.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", false);
                component.set("v.fileName", 'Alert : File size cannot exceed ' + self.MAX_FILE_SIZE + ' bytes.\n' + ' Selected file size: ' + file.size);
                return;
            }
            self.uploadFile(component, file);
        }

    },
    uploadFile:function(component, file) {
            var self = this;
           // create a FileReader object 
            var objFileReader = new FileReader();
            // set onload function of FileReader object   
            objFileReader.onload = $A.getCallback(function() {
                var fileContents = objFileReader.result;
                var base64 = 'base64,';
                var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;

                fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
                // call the uploadProcess method 
                self.uploadProcess(component, file, fileContents);
            });
            objFileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    uploadProcess: function(component, file, fileContents) {
        var self = this;
        // set a default size or startpostiton as 0 
        var startPosition = 0;
        // calculate the end size or endPostion using Math.min() function which is return the min. value   
        var endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);

        // start with the initial chunk, and set the attachId(last parameter)is null in begin
        this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, '');
    },


    uploadInChunk: function(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, attachId) {
        // call the apex method 'saveChunk'
        var getchunk = fileContents.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
        var action = component.get("c.saveChunk");

        action.setParams({
            parentId: component.get("v.parentId"),
            fileName: file.name,
            //fileName:'RaghuUpload',
            base64Data: encodeURIComponent(getchunk),
            contentType: file.type,
            //contentType: '.pptx',
            fileId: attachId
        });

        // set call back 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            // store the response / Attachment Id   
            attachId = response.getReturnValue();
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // update the start position with end postion
                startPosition = endPosition;
                endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);
                // check if the start postion is still less then end postion 
                // then call again 'uploadInChunk' method , 
                // else, diaply alert msg and hide the loading spinner
                if (startPosition < endPosition) {
                    this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, attachId);
                } else {
                    alert('your File is uploaded successfully');
                    component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", false);
                }
                // handel the response errors        
            } else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        // enqueue the action
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class FileUploadController {

    private static void appendToFile(Id fileId, String base64Data) {
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');

        Attachment a = [
            SELECT Id, Body
            FROM Attachment
            WHERE Id =: fileId
        ];

        String existingBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.Body);

        a.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(existingBody + base64Data);

        update a;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id saveChunk(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType, String fileId) {
        if (fileId == '') {
            fileId = saveTheFile(parentId, fileName, base64Data, contentType);
        } else {
            appendToFile(fileId, base64Data);
        }

        return Id.valueOf(fileId);
    }

    public static Id saveTheFile(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType) {
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');

        Attachment oAttachment = new Attachment();
        oAttachment.parentId = parentId;

        oAttachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
        oAttachment.Name = fileName;
        oAttachment.ContentType = contentType;

        insert oAttachment;

        return oAttachment.Id;
    }


}
```

Comment: Dhanik Lal Sahni,Thank you very much its working good